# unable to apply json deny policy using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, policies

I am unable to apply deny policy in gcloud.

```
gcloud beta iam policies create newdenypolicy \
--attachment-point=cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/projectid-1 \
--kind=denypolicies \
--policy-file=policy.json`
```

```
{
  "displayName": "My deny policy.",
  "rules": [
    {
      "denyRule": {
        "deniedPrincipals": [
          "principal://goog/subject/nnnxxxxx.xyz.com"
        ],
        "deniedPermissions": [
          "compute.googleapis.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the error

> ERROR: (gcloud.iam.policies.create) Failed to parse YAML from
> [policy.json]: while scanning for the next token found character '\t'
> that cannot start any token   in "policy.json", line 3, column 1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug.

Evidently (although [documented](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/iam/policies/create#--policy-file) to accept JSON|YAML), the command appears (!?) to expect YAML.

Can you try replacing `policy.json` with `policy.yaml`:

```
displayName: "My deny policy."
rules:
- denyRule:
    deniedPrincipals:
    - principal://goog/subject/nnnxxxxx.xyz.com
    deniedPermissions:
    - compute.googleapis.com
```

You can report this issue on Google's public [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)